# Where is capture time recorded in images from the Snapcam Lite wearable camera?

Tags: metadata, exiftool, time, android-app

I am using a wearable bluetooth wifi [camera](https://usa.ioncamera.com/snapcam/). How do I find the time when a particular picture was taken?

So far I have tried to look at the metadata on the jpg using [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). I am only able to see when the pictures were moved from the micro-SD card to my computer through this.

I know the data of time when the picture was taken is available. Because the camera comes with an android app, and I am able to see the time when picture was taken through the app.

But once I move the picture from the microSD card to my computer, I don't know where to find it again.

Where could this time be hiding?

**EDIT:**

(The following solution is for a Linux Machine. However for other OS, one can something similar in spirit: SAVE your metadata *before* moving the images anywhere from the MicroSD)

Using this command *before* moving the images from MicroSD card: 
`exiftool /path/to/file/filename.JPG | grep Modification`

gives the output:

```
 File Modification Date/Time     : 2017:05:20 01:47:38+05:30
```

But the actual time of creation in this case was `2017:05:19 20:17:38` which one gets by subtracting the `+5:30` for my timezone.

If one moves the file to computer the above data gets permanently over-written. So I have a bash script with which I rename the file with the time of it's creation *before* moving it anywhere.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/path/to/file"

for file in *
do 
    out="$(exiftool $file | grep Modification)"
    out=${out:34:19}
    out=${out/":"/"-"}
    out=${out/":"/"-"}
    out=$(date -d "$out")
    out=$(date -d "$out -330 minutes" +'%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')
       # Replace -330 with offset needed for your timezone
    if [[ $file == *.jpg ]]
    then
        mv "$file" "${out}.JPG"
    fi
    if [[ $file == *.MP4 ]]
    then
        mv "$file" "${out}.MP4"
    fi
done
```

I am happy with this for now.

Comment: Could you upload one of the photos somewhere *other* than Stack Exchange so someone can dig through the EXIF data? (Imgur, which Stack Exchanges uses for image hosting, unfortunately removes EXIF data).

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're using `exiftool`? Can you post the output of `exiftool`?

Comment: Suggest me a place where I can upload the photo without losing the EXIF data. I would be happy to do that.

Comment: What are the file dates of the files on the MicroSD card _before_ you move them?

Comment: *Before* moving the picture from MicroSD card, the `File Inode Change Date/Time` variable seems to be **related** to the time of capture. This is because I take pictures in time lapse mode and every picture is being incremented by 1 min. But the time is offset by some amount and I don't know yet if it will remain offset by this constant amount all the time.

Comment: What is the output of `exiftool -s -a -g1 -U ` ?  If something extra shows up with the `-U` option, then there is a data chunk that exiftool doesn't know about.  In that case, Phil Harvey, the creator of exiftool, would probably be interested in taking a look.  You can contact him on the [Exiftool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/).  If nothing else shows up, then it's probably using the system timestamps, such as FileCreateDate or FileModifyDate.

Comment: The Android app (or possibly the camera) might be retaining some information about those files. You can test this by checking the image date of `fileA.jpg` and `fileB.jpg` (just pick two files on your card, `fileA` and `fileB` are placeholders) in the app, then remove the MicroSD card. On your computer, swap the file names of the two files, and put the MicroSD card back. If the Android app shows the same file date for `fileA` both before and after filename swapping, then the data is not coming from within the file; it's being stored externally to the file.

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes on my part. 1. `File Modification Date/Time` from the metadeta is probably what the app is detecting. 2. But this variable is offset by the timezone I am in. 3. On replacing the picture back in the microSD card after sometime (i.e. - not immediately) the APP also gets it wrong. So mystery is resolved. I am adding a bash script above which will permanently extract the time of creation to the filename.

Comment: Glad to hear your issue is resolved! Please write up your findings as an answer to your question (basically, your last comment), and then mark your answer as the accepted answer. You get the points, and Photo.SE gets another closed question! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The following solution is for a Linux Machine. However for other OS, one can something similar in spirit: SAVE your metadata *before* moving the images anywhere from the MicroSD)

Using this command *before* moving the images from MicroSD card: `exiftool /path/to/file/filename.JPG | grep Modification`

gives the output:

`File Modification Date/Time     : 2017:05:20 01:47:38+05:30`

But the actual time of creation in this case was `2017:05:19 20:17:38` which one gets by subtracting the `+5:30` for my timezone.

If one moves the file to computer the above data gets permanently over-written. So I have a bash script with which I rename the file with the time of it's creation *before* moving it anywhere.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/path/to/file"

for file in *
do 
    out="$(exiftool $file | grep Modification)"
    out=${out:34:19}
    out=${out/":"/"-"}
    out=${out/":"/"-"}
    out=$(date -d "$out")
    out=$(date -d "$out -330 minutes" +'%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')
       # Replace -330 with offset needed for your timezone
    if [[ $file == *.jpg ]]
    then
        mv "$file" "${out}.JPG"
    fi
    if [[ $file == *.MP4 ]]
    then
        mv "$file" "${out}.MP4"
    fi
done
```

I am happy with this for now.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest saving the timestamp directly into the file metadata.  You can do this and rename an entire directory with a single exiftool command.

Try this:
`exiftool -globalTimeShift -5:30 -d '%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S.%%e' '-ModifyDate<FileModifyDate#' '-CreateDate<FileModifyDate#' '-DateTimeOriginal<FileModifyDate#' '-Filename<FileModifyDate' /path/to/Target/Dir`

**Breakdown:**
`-globalTimeShift -5:30`: Shifts all date/time tags.  In this case, subtracts the 5 hours, 30 minutes you need to shift by.
`-d '%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S.%%e'`: Reformats all date tags into the format you want to use to rename your file.
`'-ModifyDate<FileModifyDate#'`…: Copies the `FileModifyDate` into the three tags listed (`DateTimeOriginal`, `CreateDate`, and `ModifyDate`), shifted as mentioned above.  The hashtag tells exiftool to use the tag unmodified by the `-d` option.  Exiftool would have worked fine without it in this case, but if the `-d` option were different, e.g. you were using US date format, it might be affected and save an incorrect timestamp.
`'-Filename<FileModifyDate'`: Renames the file to your desired format.

You will find this to be much faster than a script, especially in the case of a large amount of files, as exiftool has to startup only once rather than once for every file.

**Additional:**
Add `-r` if you want to recurse into subdirectories.  Add `-overwrite_original` to avoid making backup `_original` files.